# Why done property of c3js's unload doesn't work stable in Lightning App Builder

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

Could you please tell me why this property (done) in c3js unload doesn't work stable Lightning App Builder? I really appreciate any help.

Follow this demo:
[Demo in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/wLz8hauj/75/)

I was trying to clone the above demo to  Lightning Component - unloadComp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <div aura:id="chart"></div>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/C3js/c3.min.css" 
                  scripts="/resource/test3" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Running the above with lightning application - test give me a result as above demo:

```
<aura:application >
    <c:unloadComp />
</aura:application>
```

and this is the result: 
[image: Result when running in Lightning Application]

But when I put it in a lightning app builder, the unload is trigger but the current data doesn't unload, and done function doesn't call as the below result image.

[image: Result when running in Lightning App Builder]

Controller

```
afterLoad : function(component, event, helper) {

        var iElem = component.find("chart").getElement();
        chart.chartView(iElem);
    }
```

test3.js link: [test3.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ean8crzMiGNkdTeEQ4RnYxU2s)

Comment: Please post your controller code as well to better assist?

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, I have added the controller code. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Sorry I meant your test3 file as well

Comment: Also where chat.chartview() function defined?

Comment: Excuse me for my lack of attachment. I've just added test3.js file. chart.chartView(iElement) defined in test3.js.

Comment: Check this out https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm .Looks like you need to use $A.getCallback() where you are setting setTimeOut to reRender the modified component

Comment: Thank you! I did try with $A.getCallback, the issue still remain. Somehow, when it runs in lightning application (LA), done is executed and everything work as I expected, but if it runs in lightning app builder (LAB), done is not executed, and even the datas don't unload. I still working around with this to figure it out. :)